# Programmatically create categories and sub-categories Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to create categories and sub-categories programmatically in wordpress. 
And once the hierarchical category is created I assign that specific post to that category. One post can only have one category. So I am setting the tag to 
`false` in

> wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $cat_id['term_id'], false );

and cat_id is received by doing this

> $cat_id = wp_insert_term($split_name[$i], 'category', array('slug' => $split_slug[$i], 'parent'=> term_exists($split_name[$i-1] , 'category' )['term_id']));

split_name variable have category name. and split_slug includes slug of that category.

Before using `wp_set_post_categories` i was using `wp_set_object_terms` in which i was passing slug. this works fine but when some categories have same slug in different hierarchy of categories it appends parent slug to child slug to keep it unique.

this above code works fine if new hierarchy is created in category. But breaks when existing category is used.

**Overall code is as follow**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($split_slug); $i++) {
                if($i == 0) {
                    $cat_id = wp_insert_term($split_name[$i], 'category', array('slug' => $split_slug[$i]));
                    if(count($split_slug) == 1) {
                        if ($cat_id) {
                            //wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $split_slug[$i], 'category', true); 
                            wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $cat_id['term_id'], false ); // setting it to false remove all previous categories associated to that post
                            add_term_meta ($cat_id['term_id'], 'objectID', $_POST['location_id'], false);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $cat_id = wp_insert_term($split_name[$i], 'category', array('slug' => $split_slug[$i], 'parent'=> term_exists($split_name[$i-1] , 'category' )['term_id']));
                    if($i == (count($split_slug)-1)){
                        if($cat_id){
                            //wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $split_slug[$i], 'category', true); 
                            wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $cat_id['term_id'], false ); // setting it to false remove all previous categories associated to that post
                            add_term_meta ($cat_id['term_id'], 'objectID', $_POST['location_id'], false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

this above code works fine when new hierarchy is created in category but breaks when post is assign to existing category. I believe the issue is the result return from wp_insert_term.

help me out.